# Parenthetical element: Comma or dash?

Tags: commas, dashes, parentheticals, parenthetical-commas

I am unsure when to use comma and when to use dashes when writing parenthetical elements in as sentence. For instance:

1. He answered - or at least he tried to answer - the question
   correctly.
2. He answered, or at least he tried to answer, the question
   correctly.

How do I choose between these two constructions?

I am also wondering whether I can mix between commas and dashes in the same text? I should obviously use the same symbol around the same parenthetical element, but what if I introduced another parenthetical element on the next page in the same text? Could that be using commas if the first was using dashes?

Comment: Choose between them any way you like, bearing in mind that you are under no obligation to be consistent in what you choose this time, or any time.

Comment: The em-dash adds drama—a big break. If it's too theatrical for that spot, you have the commas. I'd use dashes there.